# how to retrive different mp3 file from given in different key in plist file?

Tags: objective-c

I beginner of iPhone. I have taken plist file in that I have define below code..

```
<key>Animalsound</key>
    <array>
        <string>africanwilddog.mp3</string>
        <string>anteater.mp3</string>
        <string>baboon.mp3</string>
        <string>bat.mp3</string>
        <string>bear.mp3</string>
        <string>bison.mp3</string>
        <string>blackpanther.mp3</string>
    </array>
 <key>Birdsound</key>
    <array>
        <string>albatross.mp3</string>
        <string>antilleangrackle.mp3</string>
        <string>arcticloon.mp3</string>
        <string>beeeater.mp3</string>
        <string>beltedkingfisher.mp3</string>
        <string>bittern.mp3</string>
</array>
```

so, **how different key retrive from plist file** for that purpose I have used below code..

```
-(IBAction)onclicksound:(id)sender
{
        path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Animalfile" ofType:@"plist"];
        dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
        animalaudio=[pathdata valueForKey:@"Animalsound"];
        NSLog(@"animalaudio:%@",animalaudio);
        selectanimalaudio=[animalaudio objectAtIndex:currentsound];
        NSString *soundpath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:selectanimalaudio ofType:@"mp3"];
        NSLog(@"selectaudio:%@",selectanimalaudio);
        NSLog(@"selectpath:%@",soundpath);
          AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundpath]  error:NULL];
        self.audiosound=audioplayer;
        [audioplayer release];
         [audiosound play];
        NSLog(@"audioplayer:%@",audioplayer);
}
```

But when I run this code. It gives run time error of

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' and selectpath:(null)

so, give me any suggestion and source which is helpful in my apps...

Comment: The `AVAudioPlayer` line is the only one I see calling `NSURL`. Your string parameter must be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
NSString *soundpath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:selectanimalaudio ofType:@"mp3"];
```

what you search is a file that has name *selectanimalaudio* (f.e. bison.mp3) and extension "mp3", so what you search is "**bison.mp3.mp3**", but i bet that this file doesn't exist and it must return **nil**, so `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundpath]` will fail